# Frame rate of 11 FPS in World of Warcraft after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: macos, games

Any ideas why this started after upgrading to Yosemite? I checked the activity monitor and not much else is going on the network.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are facing a known issue. Wait for an update I suppose.
http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/14926302581#3